# Pass Options object with option kwargs in BrowserStack

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, browserstack

I'm trying to do something very easy with BrowserStack using selenium and python 3. Let's say this is my capability:

```
caps =
[
  {
    'os_version': '10',
    'os': 'Windows',
    'browser': 'chrome',
    'browser_version': '96.0',
    'name': 'Parallel Test1',  # test name
    'build': 'browserstack-build-1'  # Your tests will be organized within this build
  }
]
```

Now, say all I want to do is to visit google. Here is the code:

```
driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor='https://myBrowserStackCode',desired_capabilities=caps[1])
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
driver.quit()
```

It does work, but `desired_capabilities` has been deprecated, and I get asked to 'pass in an Options object with options kwarg'. I don't know what that means. Should I go with something
like this?

```
options=webdriver.ChromeOptions()
```

How am I supposed to pass `caps` then? What if I had more than one cap in the `caps`, each with different browsers?

Comment: "and I get asked to 'pass in an Options object with options kwarg'. I don't know what that means." Well, what does the documentation say? " Should I go with something like this?" That certainly looks like what was described, yes. "How am I supposed to pass caps then?" Well, did you try reading the documentation for the `webdriver.ChromeOptions` class? "What if I had more than one cap in the caps, each with different browsers?" Just... make more than one `Options` object and choose from them, the same way you choose from the caps dicts now? I don't see the problem.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I read the documents, still don't seem to be smart enough! Say I have this:     chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions(). How can I pass a predefined cap to it? I'm talking about caps[1].

Comment: Please see the linked duplicate.